# Requesting list of groups in Auth0-Authorization extension but returns 403:Insufficient scope error

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, auth0

I've installed the `Authorization` extension in my Auth0 account, so authorization functionality works perfectly but now I want to access all the groups I've created there in that authorization extension. So I've followed Authorization docs but when I use the token I've generated for that it throws `403: Insufficient scope` error in response.

These are the steps I've gone through:

1.Requested a token:

```
 curl -X POST \
  https://my_domain.auth0.com/oauth/token \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "client_id":"auth0-authorization-extension-api-client-id",
    "client_secret":"auth0-authorization-extension-api-secret",
    "audience":"urn:auth0-authz-api",
    "grant_type":"client_credentials"
}'
```

> Response:
>
> ```
> {"access_token":"encoded_access_token","expires_in":86400,"token_type":"Bearer"}
> ```

2.Requested group list:

```
 curl -X GET \
  https://domain.us.webtask.io/some_hash/api/groups \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer access_token'
```

> Response:
>
> ```
> {
>   "statusCode": 403,
>   "error": "Forbidden",
>   "message": "Insufficient scope"
> }
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully this isn't a problem still for you, but if it is:

1. Go to your Auth0 dashboard
2. Click on APIs
3. You should have an API called auth0-authorization-extension-api
4. Select Non-interactive clients tab
5. Select the client you want to give access to and change toggle to Authorized
6. There's a drop down arrow beside the authorized toggle, click that and under scopes give access to read:groups. You may need read:users too.

Hope that helps, thanks

Kevin